# Does camera1394 support UDP transport layer?

Tags: ros, camera1394, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to stream video from my gumstix Overo to my laptop with camera1394 package. With default TCP layer, I found there are 5 to 10 seconds delay and the frame rate is just about 1 frame/sec (which is not what I set 15 frames/sec). I know I need to compress image and I will do some research on that later.

Right now, I really want to change the data transport layer from TCP to UDP because UDP is batter for tele-operation. I know that I can change the transport layer by transport hint in subscriber node. So I did that in my image_view source code "image_nodelet.cpp".

At line 118, I changed:

```
image_transport::TransportHints hints(transport, ros::TransportHints(), getPrivateNodeHandle());
```

to

```
image_transport::TransportHints hints(transport, ros::TransportHints().udp(), getPrivateNodeHandle());
```

And rosmake it again. Then I run the image_view to receive video. However I found it still utilize TCP transport layer instead of UDP. Does camera1394 support UDP transport layer?

My laptop have Ubuntu 12.04 running as a virtual machine and bridged the host network. I inspect the transport layer by wireshark in windows(host). I also doubt that if I make the right image_view package I edited because I know there is another one in /opt/ros/groovy/stacks. But I my ROS_PAKCKAGE_PATH is

```
/home/adrian/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

So I think rosmake should make the source image_view in my workspace.

Thanks and have a good day!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56643/does-camera1394-support-udp-transport-layer?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-02-28**:
I remember trying a couple of months ago to send images over UDP (with Electric probably) and communication was kind of unstable (sometimes the node just crashed). (I think I have been too lazy at that time to open a ticket regarding this issue, sorry!)

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-01**:
I heard that UDP transport might be unstable, but I still want to try since I really concern about latency. Do you mind telling me how you send images over UDP? Did you just edit the transport hint in subscriber node? Thanks!

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-03-03**:
Yes this is how I did it. You should also consider trying tcpNoDelay, it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is definitely no explicit code in camera1394 for UDP transport. Publishing the `sensor_msgs/Image` and `sensor_msgs/CameraInfo` messages is actually done in [image_transport](http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport), not in the driver, itself.

Since you seem uncertain which **image_view** you are using, run this command:

```
$ rospack find image_view
```

I have never attempted to use UDP with camera1394, and have no idea whether it will work reliably or not. It is certainly worth trying, if that's what you need.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-28**:
Did you use UDP with other nodes before? As far as I know, I just need to edit ros::TransportHints() in subscriber source file. Is it right?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-28**:
I found the description of image_transport package description is "image_transport should always be used to subscribe to and publish images". Does image_view also use image_transport to subscribe to images? If yes, I might need to edit the source code in image_transport package.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-01**:
Yes, image_view subscribes using image_transport. My impression is that UDP transport with ROS is not fully functional, but I have no personal experience using it.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-01**:
Is image_transport just a library? I am not supposed to change anything in image_transport, right?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-01**:
image_transport is a ROS package, which provides a library and a republish node. You can check out the source and modify it, to experiment with UDP. Making a patch that could actually be merged back into the master source tree would probably be tricky.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-01**:
I have two image_transport packages, one on my gumstix Overo side and one on my laptop. Which one do I need to modify? I heard I just need to set image_transport::TransportHints to udp() in subscriber node. I am really confused, does it mean I need to modify image_transport package on my laptop?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-02**:
I am not sure, maybe someone else knows the answer. You can just experiement and see what happens. You can use something like wireshark to see what packets are transmitted.